# infinite scroll not working when logged out

Tags: ajax, infinite-scroll

**The problem:** infinite loop works only when the user is logged and then it shows posts that were not published yet. Once I log out, the infinite scroll doesn't work anymore.

**The setup:** I have the following custom infinite loop function:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_zephyr_infinite_scroll', 'zephyr_get_nextpage');  

function zephyr_get_nextpage() {
    $loopFile = $_POST['loop_file'];
    $paged = $_POST['page_no'];
    $vv = stripslashes($_POST['vars']);
    $vars = json_decode($vv, true);
    $vars['paged'] = $paged;
    global $isms;
    global $zephyr_post_columns;
    $zephyr_post_columns = $vars['columns'];
    unset($vars['columns']);
    $isms = $_POST['mas'];
    query_posts($vars);
    global $wp_query; 
    if ( $wp_query->found_posts == 0 ) { 
        echo 0;
    } else {
        get_template_part( 'templates/'.$loopFile );
    }
    exit;  
}
```

Then I have in my `loop.php` file:

```
<?php global $zephyr_cont; 
    global $zephyr_post_layout;
    global $zephyr_i;
    global $isms;
    global $zephyr_post_columns;
    $zephyr_i = 0;
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php 
        if ( $isms == 'true' ) {
            $zephyr_i++;
            get_template_part( 'templates/post', 'masonry'.get_post_format() );
        } else {
            get_template_part( 'templates/post', get_post_format() );
        }
    endwhile; else : ?>
        <h2><?php _e('No posts found, go ', 'zephyr'); ?> <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>"><?php _e('home', 'zephyr'); ?></a>?</h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

And the `script.js` file:

```
function loadArticle(pageNumber) {
        $('#ajaxload').fadeIn(300);
        $.ajax({  
            url: Zephyr.ajaxurl,  
            type:'POST',  
            data: {
                action : 'zephyr_infinite_scroll',
                page_no : pageNumber,
                loop_file : 'loop',
                vars : Zephyr.queryvars,
                mas : isms
            },   
            success: function(html){
                if ( html !== '0' ) {
                    if ( isms ) {
                        $zephyr_container.isotope( 'insert', $(html) );
                    } else {
                        $(html).hide().appendTo('#content').fadeIn('300');
                    }
                    layoutSidebar(ms);
                } else {
                    noload = 1;
                }
                $('#ajaxload').fadeOut(300);
            }  
        });  
        return false;  
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add this before your other add_action call:

`add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_zephyr_infinite_scroll', 'zephyr_get_nextpage');`

the `wp_ajax_` filter runs only when you are logged in. `wp_ajax_nopriv_` runs only when logged out. This is so you can separate your requests, and maybe treat them differently, if that's the case.

Check [wp_ajax_(action)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_%28action%29)

Comment: Yep, this is the answer.  I just want to add the obligatory, "don't use query_posts()" to the OP.  See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts

Comment: hadn't even seen that. Good catch :)